# Lag in rotation 2D

Tags: php, javascript, bitmap, rotation, 2d

I have a bitmap (web ‹img›, 2048x1365) and put a dot on it (‹div› absolute with size 1px).
When I rotate the bitmap (on server), I want to rotate the dot as well (with Javascript).

I know the equation of rotation :

```
$cs=cos($radian);
$sn=sin($radian);

$x2=($x*$cs)-($y*$sn);
$y2=($x*$sn)+($y*$cs);
```

But somehow I have a lag...

My code (in PHP) :

```
$width=2048;
$height=1365;

$radian=$rot*M_PI/180;

$cs=cos($radian);
$sn=sin($radian);

$center_x=$width/2;
$center_y=$height/2;

$x-=$center_x;
$y-=$center_y;

$x2=($x*$cs)-($y*$sn);
$y2=($x*$sn)+($y*$cs);

$x=$x2+$center_x;
$y=$y2+$center_y;
```

With $rot=6°, I must shift (about) $x2 +30, $y2 +85
 
With $rot=21°, I must shift $x2 +40, $2 +380
With $rot=90°, I must shift $x2 -340, $y2 -340
With $rot=180°, It's good
With $rot=270°, I must shift $x2 +340, $y2 +340

I don't understand this lag...

To help, [here is an example](http://server6.einden.com/test.jpg). The dots are the centers of the square. With angle 10°, I must add x+180 and y+70 for the 3 dots.

Thank you very much for your help

Comment: Doesn't the image size *change* when it is rotated?

Comment: To help, [here is an example](http://server6.einden.com/test.jpg). The dots are the centers of the square. With angle 10°, I must add x+180 and y+70 for the 3 dots. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Anony-Mousse > The jpeg is always the same size but actually changes the image size ([see example](http://server6.einden.com/test.jpg), change with ImageMagick). How to calculate the change?

Comment: Compute the positions of the corners after rotation and you should get the rotated image size.

Comment: The problem was simple: the center of the image changes with the rotation ... So simple that I do not think :) Thank you for the help

Answer (score 0):

Copy from the comments to the question:

Doesn't the image size *change* when it is rotated?

Compute the positions of the corners after rotation and you should get the rotated image size

(from which you then can compute the new rotation center.)